# Query many-to-many relationship tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've got these tables with a relationship n:m:

```
1) NEW
ID_NEW, TITLE_NEW, SUBTITLE_NEW, CONTENT_NEW, CREATED_NEW, IMAGE_NEW, USER_ID

2) TAG
ID_TAG, NAME_TAG

3) NEW_has_TAG
NEW_ID, TAG_ID
```

I would like to find a query which looks for a specific tag, for example a tag which is 'football'. In that case if it founds something, a list with the id of the new(s), title, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic SQL with joins:

```
SELECT
  t.*, n.*
FROM
  tag t
  LEFT JOIN new_has_tag nt ON t.id_tag = nt.id_tag
  LEFT JOIN `new` n ON nt.new_id = n.id_new
WHERE
  t.name_tag = 'football'
```

Actually [`NEW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) is a reserved keyword in SQL Standard (MySQL also follows this standard) so you probably have a table named **`new`** with backticks instead of `new`.

If you have [ANSI SQL mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) enabled, then `"new"` would also be a valid name for identifier.

Comment: Will the double quote work, or do you need the single back tick around `new`?

Comment: If the ANSI SQL mode is enabled, ten double quote would work. Thanks for the addition, I've changed it to backticks, as this is mostly the case.

Comment: Thank you so much! 
It works with single quotes and without them, at least in MySQL :)

Comment: There are plenty of sites that offer free basic SQL tutorials. You could check http://www.w3schools.com/sql/ for example